# Agrupar resultados SQL por data

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, unix

Então, possuo uma tabela que registra o login dos jogadores, todos os valores em unix timestamp, e queria saber como faço pra saber o dia em que houveram mais registros, e, somando o total, o dia em que houveram mais SEG_Online, AJ_Enviadas e LVL_Upado.

[image: Tabela]

Usando função FROM_UNIXTIME:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que pode ser utilizado o  `GROUP BY`. Outra sugestão, nas perguntas é interessante postar o texto do código com a estrutura da tabela (CREATE TABLE) e dos outros trechos de código, fica mais fácil para quem for te ajudar com o problema.

Comment: Pedro se possível poste a estrutura e a consulta no SQL Fiddle, para auxiliarmos fica melhor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agrupar por data e somar as colunas seg_online, aj_enviadas e lvl_upado basta fazer o seguinte:

```
select from_unixtime(ts_sessao, '%d/%m/%Y') data, sum(seg_online) seg_online, 
sum(aj_enviadas) aj_enviadas , sum(lvl_upado) lvl_upado
from logins
group by data;
```

Resultado:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| data       | seg_online | aj_enviadas | lvl_upado |
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 07/10/2018 |        105 |           7 |         9 |
| 08/10/2018 |        220 |           3 |         4 |
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Agora, para conseguir o valor máximo de cada coluna, faça um select buscando a data e o valor da coluna desejada.

```
select aux.data, max(aux.lvl_upado) quantidade_lvl_upado from (
select from_unixtime(ts_sessao, '%d/%m/%Y') data, sum(seg_online) seg_online, 
sum(aj_enviadas) aj_enviadas , sum(lvl_upado) lvl_upado
from logins
group by data) aux;
```

Retorno:

```
+------------+----------------------+
| data       | quantidade_lvl_upado |
+------------+----------------------+
| 07/10/2018 |                    9 |
+------------+----------------------+
```

Para saber as outras colunas basta trocar na linha 1 a coluna **aux.lvl_upado** pela coluna desejada.

Comment: Consegui, obrigado

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, por nada!